# How to convert float list to int list in python

Tags: python, sorting

```
a= [6248.570994, 5282.059503, 5165.000653, 5130.795058, 5099.376451]
```

one way:

```
a=map(int, a)
```

the other way:

```
int_a=[]
for intt in a:
   int_a.append(int(intt))
```

above ways can print right answer,but when I want sorted I met problem:

```
maxx=sorted(int_a,reverse=True)[:1]*1.2
print maxx

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: can you put complete traceback?

Comment: I find the reason ....I can't add " *1.2"  to the sorted or it will go wrong.

Comment: do you want an output like this : `[6248, 5282, 5165, 5130, 5099]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that

```
maxx=sorted(int_a,reverse=True)[:1]*1.2
print maxx
```

... produces a list, not an integer and you cannot multiply a list by a floating point number. To obtain 1.2 times the maximum element in the list using this code, the following would work:

```
maxx=sorted(int_a,reverse=True)[0]*1.2
print maxx
```

... though it would be more efficient to use:

```
maxx=max(int_a)*1.2
print maxx
```

Comment: This fixes the `TypeError` and works, but to find the maximum element multiplied by 1.2 it would make a lot more sense to do `max(int_a) * 1.2`

Comment: I agree that `max(int_a)` would be better if the goal is to find the maximum element multiplied by 1.2.

Comment: I misunderstand list and number .Thinks a lot .

Answer (score 1):

Any specific reason why you are not using [max](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max)? 
It your statement could simply be:

`print max(int_a) * 1.2`